# How to call javascript function for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

So there is this code that i have copied from w3schools.com:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's a code for making an image gallery. The problem is that when there is more than one div named slideshow-gallery, the javascript applies the function to only one div. So my question is how to call the function for multiple divs that has the same name? any ideas?
And thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried to add flexibility to it by changing the elements from variables to parameters and then passing the element you want the slideshow to be on as an argument to the functions. Unfortunately, it became too cumbersome, so you have to reconstruct it while keeping the concepts of functions and parameters in mind

Comment: Could you please send me the code

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already deleted it. And it got REAL messy. You don't want to work with that. I told you, try to pass the elements as arguments to the functions, not hardcode them to variables at the beginning of the code

Comment: Is there any way to do this in jquery? by giving a specific id to these divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is 100% exactly related to what you are looking for.

But there are at least 3 ways of doing this in JavaScript.

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
let divs = document.querySelector("div");
```

All 3 method will return exactly the same HTMLCollection, containing all of the selected elements.

Problem is, HTMLCollection is not an iterable.

Good news, though. To convert it you can use Object.entries method:

```
Object.entries(divs).map(( object ) => {
    object[1].addEventListener("click", function() {    
        console.log("Hello " + this + " (" + this.innerHTML + ") from map method...");
    });
});
```

**object[1]** is the link to the "any" object on the list. Here simply a click event was added to every element. As far as your case, you can do whatever you need here.

Further: this [tutorial about selecting multiple elements](http://javascriptteacher.com/call-javascript-on-multiple-div-elements.html?s=so) from which I have taken this example might be of use.